# my Note3 isn't compatible with my application

Tags: android

I'm sorry I'm gonna be blunt, but I can't figure out why my application doesn't support Note3 this is my manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="true"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="true"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false"/>



<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"/>


<compatible-screens>
     <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, the Note 3 does not fit your `<compatible-screens>` element, perhaps due to a different density.

Generally speaking, `<compatible-screens>` is a rather risky element to use, as it is a whitelist (i.e., what devices are acceptable) rather than a blacklist (i.e., what devices should be dropped). So, for example, you do not support `-xxhdpi` devices, `-tvdpi` devices, `DENSITY_400` devices, etc. Hence, I strongly encourage you to get rid of `<compatible-screens>` entirely.

Comment: Though I want to support only normal and large screens.Is the <supports-screens> tag sufficient? also is there a way that I can check the supported devices according to my manifest before publishing it to google play?

Comment: @libathos: "Though I want to support only normal and large screens" -- saying that you want to avoid `-small` screens is easy enough. Saying that you want to support `-large` but not `-xlarge` does not make sense IMHO. Regardless, `<supports-screens>` can block `-small` (i.e., anything smaller than you say that you support) but it cannot block `-xlarge`. And I am not aware of a way to check the supported-device list outside of using the Developer Console for Play.

Comment: well in my project resources files are: layout-normal-port,layout-normal-land,layout-large-port/land, and the layout-xlarge files are empty.If a 10'' tablet downloads it, it will crash since it won't find the xlarge resources

Comment: @libathos: No, if an `-xlarge` device runs your app, it will use `-large` resources.

Comment: @libathos: Android won't try going in the other direction (e.g., a `-normal` device cannot use `-large` resources). But Android will take your `-large` resources and use them for `-xlarge` devices.